# How to invoke a function from another Python script that is already running?

Tags: python, import, multiprocessing

I have two scripts: client.py and bot.py. When I execute bot.py alongside client.py, I want client.py to send data and launch specific functions within bot.py (for your information, bot.py is a Discord bot). So, my question is: how can I execute functions within bot.py's context without creating a new instance of the bot(importing .py file), and ideally, with the ability to pass arguments?

```
#client.py
choice = input("Enter number: )
if choice == "1":
    #HERE IS bot.py FUNCTION LAUNCH
```

```
#bot.py
def func():
    send_message('hi')
```

I tryed user multiprocessing, import, importlib, but this didn't help.
I will glad to any help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want is communication between processes: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html

Answer (score -2):

Walrus to recuse Python 3.8 or later.

Snippet:

```
if [choice := input("Enter number: ")] != '1':
    import bot
    bot.func()
```

Output:

hi